# File path incorrect after moving Magento

Tags: magento

Tried migrating a magento install from one domain/server to another.  Now when I view the site on the test install it only partially loads (missing product images and footer) and when I view the error logs it looks like it is adding a /var/www/vhosts/....  to some filepaths so it seems like they dont exist.

I cannot seem to find this filepath anywhere and dont know where I should change it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my error log:

```
[Thu Jan 16 20:22:19 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Thu Jan 16 20:22:19 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Parallels Panel' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Jan 17 01:08:23 2014] [error] [client 5.5.5.5] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/HNAP1, referer: http://500.500.500.500/
[Fri Jan 17 01:18:15 2014] [error] [client 0.0.0.0] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/HNAP1, referer: http://500.500.500.500/
[Fri Jan 17 07:11:10 2014] [error] [client 10.10.10.10] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/HNAP1, referer: http://500.500.500.500/
[Fri Jan 17 08:37:34 2014] [error] [client 250.250.250.250] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/HNAP1, referer: http://500.500.500.500/
[Fri Jan 17 16:46:12 2014] [error] [client 75.75.75.75] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/HNAP1, referer: http://500.500.500.500/
[Fri Jan 17 17:28:40 2014] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/php
[Fri Jan 17 17:28:56 2014] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/php
[Fri Jan 17 17:43:03 2014] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/php
[Fri Jan 17 17:45:56 2014] [error] [client 1.1.1.1] script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/php
[Fri Jan 17 21:14:57 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:14:57 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:14:57 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:15:03 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/inspiration, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:15:06 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:15:06 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:15:06 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:30 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:30 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:30 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:35 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:36 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:37 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:37 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:16:38 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:18:31 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:18:31 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:18:31 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:19:46 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/shop, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:19:47 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/shop, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:19:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:19:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:19:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:20:07 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:20:07 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:20:07 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:20:15 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/lookbook, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:20:19 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:22:33 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/admin
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:00 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:00 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:00 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:27 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:27 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:27 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:27 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:27 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:39 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:39 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:39 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:46 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013?p=2
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:46 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013?p=2
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:46 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013?p=2
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:54 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:56 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:56 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:27:56 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:28:36 2014] [error] [client 7.7.7.7] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/instafeed.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:28:36 2014] [error] [client 7.7.7.7] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/new-window.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:28:36 2014] [error] [client 7.7.7.7] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js, referer: http://test.test-site.com/
[Fri Jan 17 21:32:29 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:32:29 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:32:29 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:32:29 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:46:40 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 21:46:40 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 22:06:02 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/wysiwyg/picwithcorner_copy.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/inspiration
[Fri Jan 17 22:06:04 2014] [error] [client 75.75.75.75] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/wysiwyg/picwithcorner_copy.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/catalog/category/view/id/40/
[Fri Jan 17 22:06:05 2014] [error] [client 15.15.15.15] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/wysiwyg/picwithcorner_copy.jpg
[Fri Jan 17 22:06:11 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 22:06:11 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 22:19:39 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Fri Jan 17 22:19:39 2014] [error] [client 100.100.100.100] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:33:39 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:33:39 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:33:44 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 14:34:29 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:34:29 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:34:47 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 14:35:26 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:35:27 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:35:32 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/fall-2013
[Sat Jan 18 14:36:42 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/chill_blanket.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:36:42 2014] [error] [client 99.99.99.99] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/media/catalog/category/heart_image_white_background.jpg, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop
[Sat Jan 18 14:37:09 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 14:39:06 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 14:39:11 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 14:39:30 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 14:41:38 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 14:42:26 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 14:47:16 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 14:47:51 2014] [warn] [client 85.85.85.85] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0
[Sat Jan 18 14:53:35 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:07:21 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:07:23 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:07:24 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:07:25 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:07:26 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 946, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:09:05 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:09:34 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Facebook_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 546, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:09:41 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Facebook_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 546, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:09:57 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:10:32 2014] [error] [client 500.500.500.500] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
[Sat Jan 18 15:10:45 2014] [error] [client 500.500.500.500] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
[Sat Jan 18 15:11:13 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:12:40 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:14:51 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:15:10 2014] [error] [client 500.500.500.500] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
[Sat Jan 18 15:15:23 2014] [error] [client 500.500.500.500] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
[Sat Jan 18 15:15:29 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:15:38 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:18:00 2014] [warn] [client 85.85.85.85] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0
[Sat Jan 18 15:23:48 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/all
[Sat Jan 18 15:30:58 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Unleaded_Facebook_Block_Plugin_Widget' not found in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget/Like.php on line 9, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:32:01 2014] [error] [client 500.500.500.500] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
[Sat Jan 18 15:39:20 2014] [warn] [client 99.99.99.99] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0, referer: http://test.test-site.com/shop/cruise-14
[Sat Jan 18 15:51:09 2014] [warn] [client 85.85.85.85] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0
[Sat Jan 18 15:51:35 2014] [warn] [client 85.85.85.85] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0
[Sat Jan 18 15:55:15 2014] [warn] [client 85.85.85.85] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Method Unleaded_Facebook_Helper_Data::__toString() must not throw an exception in /var/www/vhosts/live-website.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Unleaded/Facebook/Block/Plugin/Widget.php on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing all caches under:
System > Cache Management
and click the Flush Magento Cache button. This helped in my case.

Comment: Thanks @marcinsdance, that did not seem to work though.. It looks like everything is loading fine except for the product page.  For some reason the product data is there but the product image,sidebar and the footer dont load on the single product pages

Comment: Yes, just double checked by deleting everything again manually and it still does not show the sidebar, footer and product image on single product page.  Cant figure it out, could it be something else maybe?

Comment: hi Derek, did you try these steps? Maybe try to reset permissions as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141873/why-is-magento-1-4-including-javascript-files-by-filesystem-path/14439716#14439716 Also make sure that the root directory of Magento has got proper permissions (depending on your server settings, it's either 733, 755 or 777).